# How to uninstall Anki from Suse Linux

Tags: linux, uninstall, opensuse, anki

I tried uninstalling it from YAST2 software manager but I found that it is marked as uninstalled.
Then I tried from command line

```
sudo zypper rm anki
```

and got this

> Loading repository data...
>   Reading installed packages...
>   'anki' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
>   No provider of 'anki' found.
>   Resolving package dependencies...
>   Nothing to do.

---

I installed anki on my system using the instructions on their [homepage](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) which is: 
***downloading the compiled package then running:***

> $ tar xjf Downloads/anki-2.0.45-amd64.tar.bz2
>   $ cd anki-2.0.45
>   $ sudo make install

And I'm using a custom made SUSE Linux based on openSUSE Leap 42.1 JeOS

Comment: When you compile software from source, you are bypassing the package manager (YAST2), which means you are not able to use the package manager to uninstall the software. The package manager is unaware the software is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many other software that is compiled from source you can uninstall it by running the following command from within the source:
If you used '***make install***' then run

```
make uninstall
```

If you used '***sudo make install***' then run

```
sudo make uninstall
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahmad Mysra saved me HOURS! I almost had to reinstall Ubuntu because of this issue from Anki. Ahmad Mysra's method works! Just to make it a clearer:

$ tar xjf Downloads/anki-2.0.45-amd64.tar.bz2

$ cd anki-2.0.45

$ sudo make uninstall